# How to define a generic comparable array class?

Tags: java, generics

I want to define a generic class ComparableList<> that extend ArrayList and implements Comparable interfaces, such that two objects of type ComparableList can be compared using the compareTo method. The compareTo should perform a lexicographic comparison. 
Here's my code:

```
class ComparableList <T extends Comparable<T>> extends ArrayList implements Comparable<ComparableList>{
@Override
    public int compareTo(ComparableList o){
        Iterator citer = this.iterator();
        Iterator oiter = o.iterator();
        while (citer.hasNext() && oiter.hasNext()){
            if (citer.next() > oiter.next()){
                return 1;
            }else if (citer.next() < oiter.next()){
                return -1;
            }else {
                if (!citer.hasNext()){
                    return -1;
                }
                if(!oiter.hasNext()){
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

}

and I got error messages like this:

```
TCL.java:11: error: bad operand types for binary operator '>'
            if (citer.next() > oiter.next()){
                             ^
first type:  Object
second type: Object
TCL.java:13: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
            }else if (citer.next() < oiter.next()){
                                   ^
first type:  Object 
second type: Object
```

I thought it should be a ComparableList but not an Object. Can anyone tell me the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the objects using `Comparable.comapreTo()` (that's why you have `<T extends Comparable<T>` there). You need to first check for nulls on either side.

Also, each call to `Iterator.next()` iterates to next element, you don't want to call it twice in one loop iteration - store the items at the loop start then use the stored values.

Comment: I modified the code to `Iterator i = iter.next(), o = oiter.next();` but the compiler said `Object cannot be converted to Iterator` Seems like it is still not a ComparableList type

Comment: Why would you expect `iter.next()` to return an `Iterator`? It returns the next item - that one has type `T`.

Answer (score 1):

`Comparable` doesn't override the `>` and `<` operators (nothing can). Since your `T` implements `Comparable`, use `compareTo`:

```
int result = citer.next().compareTo(oiter.next());
if (result != 0) {
    return result;
} else {
    if (citer.hasNext()) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (oiter.hasNext()) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Note that that also calls `next` only **once** per iteration, since `next` advanced the iterator.

Comment: I modified my code but get `method compareTo(Object)` error. Seems like it is still an Object, not a ComparableList type I want

Answer (score 1):

Each element in your `ComparableList` is of type `T extends Comparable<T>`, for sure the binary operator is not available for it (Java doesn't have operator overloading), but since it extends `Comparable`, you have `compareTo` to be used as replacement for < and >. Use it instead.